# How do I call another micro-service from my micro-service?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

This might sound a little odd, but I'm facing a situation where I have a micro-service that assembles some pricing logic, but for that, it needs a bunch of information that another micro-service provides.

I believe I have two options: (1) grab all the data I need from the database and ignore the GraphQL work that was done in this other micro-service or (2) somehow hit this other micro-service from within my current service and get the data I need.

How would someone accomplish (2)?

I have no clear path of how to get that done without creating a mess.

I imagine that turning my pricing micro-service into a small client could work, but I'm just not sure if that's bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much consideration and reading the answers I got [here](https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-federation/how-do-i-call-another-service-from-my-service~7e4573a4-bb34-4678-b44e-91cc377d668d), I decided to turn my micro-service into a mini-client by using apollo-client.

In short, I have something like this:

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';

// Instantiate required constructor fields
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  // Provide required constructor fields
  cache: cache,
  link: link,
});

export default client;
```

That HttpLink is the federated schema, so I can call it from my resolver or anywhere else like this:

```
const query = gql`
        query {
          something(uid: "${uid}") {
            field1
            field2
            field3
            anotherThing {
              field1
              field2
            }
          }
        }
      `;
const response = await dataSources.client.query({query});
```